# Android: Getting a String from an android app through a browser call

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building a Hybrid application for android which has a `String` value stored in a variable.

I have the application installed in my mobile, and now I need to fetch the `String` value (from that hybrid app) through a JavaScript call from a browser (web page opened in the same mobile). How can I achieve this?

Forgive for the abstractness in the question, as I am a newbie to both Android and Web app development.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info Michal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, hoping it might help anyone later.

After so much of online reading, I've found it is not possible to read values embedded within another app. (Except exposing the variable through an external API as Mr. Michal Hainc pointed out rightly in the comment)